# Applescript check if window is one screen

Tags: window, applescript

I have written this script function

```
on GetWindowLocation()
    set front_app to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
    tell application front_app
        item 1 of (get bounds of front window)
    end tell
end GetWindowLocation

on GetDockStatus()
    tell application "System Events" to get the autohide of the dock preferences
end GetDockStatus
```

if I am on the desktop with no windows up it errors.
How can I check if a window is on screen,  so I can put an if statement to not
 run it if a window is not on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest fix here would be to simply catch the error:

```
tell application front_app
    try
        return item 1 of (get bounds of front window)
    on error
        -- do something here to handle there being no front window
    end try
end tell
```

You could also try checking the `count of windows` before trying to reference the `front window`, but that's somewhat more prone to errors (as the window may disappear before you grab its bounds).

Comment: OK thanks that worked perfectly here is what I was working on  http://ice-os.com/downloads/WindowDodge-1.0.tar.bz2 for OSX   tell me what you think

Comment: Interesting concept, but it appears to depend on a specific screen size and/or dock position - my system has the dock on the right side, and it doesn't respond usefully. It also constantly uses 100% CPU.

Comment: OK I will have to figure out whats wrong with it. my Dock is on the left